# How to seed uuidv4 with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to seed a uuid using sequilize generateUUID
 but i get this error `Seed file failed with error: sequelize.Utils.generateUUID is not a function TypeError: sequelize.Utils.generateUUID is not a function`

how do i seed a UUID?

```
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('companies', [{
        id: sequelize.Utils.generateUUID(),
        name: 'Testing',
        updated_at: new Date(),
        created_at: new Date()
    }]);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just install uuid:

```
npm install uuid
```

and on your seed file:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('yourTableName', [
      {
        id: uuidv4()
      }],
 {});
```

Comment: Sequelize does use `uuid` under the hood so the package should already be available. Sequelize doesn't expose the `uuidv4` method in a useful way though.

Comment: Now getting `DeprecationWarning: Deep requiring like 'const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');' is deprecated as of uuid@7.x. Please require the top-level module when using the Node.js CommonJS module or use ECMAScript Modules when bundling for the browser. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#deep-requires-now-deprecated for more information.`  And when I switch to the recommended import syntax I get a different error.

Answer (score 7):

Since it's included in the `DataTypes` package, would make sense to use what is [already available](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/data-types.js%7EUUIDV4.html) as Matt suggested. You can use it in this way:

```
{
    ...,
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow! Changing the key from "default" to "defaultValue" solved it for me. Thanks

Comment: Nice, This is far good in comparison to the above answers as sequelize have it all required for this to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

`npm install uuid`

import it on your seeder file

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

return queryInterface.bulkInsert('companies', [{
    id: uuidv4(),
    name: 'Testing',
    updated_at: new Date(),
    created_at: new Date()
}]);
```

[See more on the uuid documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Comment: I thought, the link is to Sequelize documentation

Comment: Nah... it's uuid documentation... I have updated the answer to clarify that.. thanks for pointing it out.